# Acumatica Adding Column to Files Dialog Grid

Tags: acumatica

#### Issue

I was asked if it was possible to add a column to the grid on the standard Files Dialog window in Acumatica.

#### Findings

I believe I can extend the cache to create a field in the Data Access Class (and modify the tables/create an extension table to handle the DB side), but I do not see a means to adding said field to the form as a column in the grid. There isn't any screen that corresponds to this and the smart panel isn't defined in each page. Rather it appears to be created in PX.Web.UI.PXFilesDialog. The only entry point through this appears to be the solution outlined in this article:

https://community.acumatica.com/customization-and-development-72/how-to-add-a-custom-button-to-the-files-dialog-box-4229

This access point appears to only be for adding actions to the smart panel's grid. Since adding columns to the grid is not something typically done via code in the Acumatica Framework, and decompiling the PXFilesDialog class shows that it add the columns to the grid (because it has a reference to the grid), there doesn't appear to be a way to access that.

#### Conclusion

Any help is appreciated (or at the very least, confirmation of my skepticism of this being possible).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is currently no way to add columns to that grid.
The columns are basically hardcoded inside the `PXFileDialog` control.

[image]